# How to move up my controls when they would be hidden by the soft keyboard?

Tags: android

OK, so I have this very basic layout:

[image]

As you can see, the edit texts and the login button are centered in the area below the icon. They are not aligned with the bottom. And I want to keep it this way.

Now, when the soft keyboard is shown, all I want is that the whole view is pushed upwards, so that the login button is above the soft keyboard but takes into account its lower margin.

My activity has `windowSoftInputMode` set to `adjustPan`, but it just assures that the currently focused control is visible, not all three of them:

[image]

**Question:** What do I need to change so that all three controls are visible as soon as the keyboard is visible?

This is my view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/Recson.Apps.Android"
    style="@style/Theme.Recson.NoActionBar"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/LoginViewRoot">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/Logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Icon"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/Credentials"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/Icon">
        <EditText
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            local:MvxBind="Text Username"
            android:hint="@string/Username"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/text_hint" />
        <EditText
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            local:MvxBind="Text Password"
            android:hint="@string/Password"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/text_hint" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Login"
            local:MvxBind="Click Login;Enabled CanLogin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: As per my Opinion add your layout into `ScrollView` and also set `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`  to your Activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least, the answers here show that I wasn't missing anything obvious.

I now solved it like that:

1. `windowSoftInputMode` set to `adjustResize`
2. Complete layout inside a `ScrollView`
3. On layout change, I simply scroll down the `ScrollView` to the bottom:

   ```
   public class LoginView : MvxActivity, ViewTreeObserver.IOnGlobalLayoutListener
   {
       private ScrollView _activityRootView;

       public void OnGlobalLayout()
       {
           var focusedControl = Window.CurrentFocus;
           _activityRootView.FullScroll(FocusSearchDirection.Down);
           if (focusedControl != null)
               focusedControl.RequestFocus();
           else if (Window.CurrentFocus != null)
               Window.CurrentFocus.ClearFocus();
       }

       protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
       {
           base.OnCreate(bundle);
           SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LoginView);

           _activityRootView = FindViewById<ScrollView>(Resource.Id.LoginViewRoot);
           _activityRootView.ViewTreeObserver.AddOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
       }
   }
   ```

(this is C# code using Xamarin.Android and MvvmCross. It is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9108219/572644))

This solution has one drawback: The controls are no longer centered in the area below the icon, but right now, I am OK with that:

[image]

[See it in action](http://screencast.com/t/05LJhOX9Z)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `ScrollView` and put your main layout inside it. I think it will do the job.

Comment: No change except that my controls are no longer centered.

Comment: If I additionally change `windowSoftInputMode` to `adjustResize`, the user can manually scroll down. If I could now tell the ScrollView to automatically scroll down, it would solve my problem.

Comment: Looks like scrolling isn't possible in the XML file. But it is possible in code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22043546/572644

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Manifest file.

```
<activity name="ActivityName"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
        ...
    </activity>
```

Comment: Without a `ScrollView`, `adjustResize` is even worse. It just shows half of the first input field.

Answer (score 0):

As you're experiencing, adjustPan, adjustResize etc will only try to ensure the currently focused input field is visible.

What you could try to do is remove the LinearLayout then position your username password and login views in such a way that the system thinks they occupy the same space by using layout_marginTop and layout_marginBottom.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this in your activity tag of your menifest file:

```
android:configChanges="screenSize"
```

And Use ScrollView in your Xml file something like below:
(I have changed your layout a bit):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LoginViewRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_below="@id/Icon" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Credentials"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Credentials1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:inputType="textPassword" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Login" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but this doesn't work. Basically, because the Icon doesn't move, there is not enough space between the icon and the keyboard to display the controls. Furthermore, only the login button is visible: http://screencast.com/t/ad8Be53F

Comment: Okay np, but post your answer if you get any proper solution.

Comment: Not really a proper solution, but one that works: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22043546/572644

Answer (score 0):

Used This Code :

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        App.Current.On<Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);

    }
```